# Maya only selects items starting with 1 when using group

Tags: python, maya, modeling

I am trying to get maya to select everything based on a name to be put into one group, however, every time I run the function, it selects the first item, then every item beginning with a 1. and then doesnt select anything after that. I've tried getting rid of the * but then it only selects item 1 and nothing else. How do I fix this

```
def tree(num):
    for y in range (25):
        TREY=rnd.uniform(23,40)
        TREX=rnd.randint(-10,10)
        TREZ=rnd.randint(-10,10)
        cmds.polyPlatonicSolid(n=pfx+"tree_"+str(num)+"_tree_top_"+str(num))
        cmds.move(TREX,TREY,TREZ)
        cmds.scale(4.5,4.5,4.5)

        
   cmds.group(pfx+"tree_"+str(num)+"_tree_top_"+str(num)+"*",n=pfx+"top_GRP"+str(num))
   tree(1)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your formatting is a bit off since the current version would result in an endless loop because the last line inside the function calls the function again. And the `pfx` is not defined anywhere. And see what happens if you simply replace the `num` with 1. So the name of the element to group is always the same, in your case the one with a 1.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is related to how Maya will automatically name new objects upon name clashes. Try this:

```py
import random as rnd
import maya.cmds as cmds

def tree(num):
    pfx = "prefix_"
    n = str(num)
    basename = pfx + "tree_" + n + "_tree_top_"
    name = basename + n
    groupname = pfx + "top_GRP" + n
    
    for y in range(25):
        TREY=rnd.uniform(23, 40)
        TREX=rnd.randint(-10, 10)
        TREZ=rnd.randint(-10, 10)
        cmds.polyPlatonicSolid(n=name)
        cmds.move(TREX, TREY, TREZ)
        cmds.scale(4.5, 4.5, 4.5)
    
    cmds.group(basename + "*", n=groupname)

tree(1)
```

However, a perhaps better approach is to store all the newly created objects in a list, rather than depend on name

```py
import random as rnd
import maya.cmds as cmds

def tree(num):
    pfx = "prefix_"
    n = str(num)

    name = pfx + "tree_" + n + "_tree_top_" + n
    groupname = pfx + "top_GRP" + n
    
    objs = []
    
    for y in range(25):
        TREY=rnd.uniform(23, 40)
        TREX=rnd.randint(-10, 10)
        TREZ=rnd.randint(-10, 10)
        obj = cmds.polyPlatonicSolid(n=name)[0]
        cmds.move(TREX, TREY, TREZ, obj)
        cmds.scale(4.5, 4.5, 4.5, obj)
        objs.append(obj)
    
    cmds.group(objs, n=groupname)

tree(1)
```

Note that a string array is returned from `polyPlatonicSolid()`, so to get object you need the first element `obj = cmds.polyPlatonicSolid()[0]`